# Expected number of rolls on a 200 sided die to roll a 1?

Tags: probability, dice

We have a 200 sided fair die with faces numbered 1 through 200 and want to know how many rolls are expected to roll a 1. How would I go about calculating this?

Comment: It is what you'd expect, $200$ times.

Comment: Have you learned about [geometric distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution)?

Comment: What do you mean roll a 1?  What are on the faces of the die?  I think you mean how many rolls are expected.

Comment: -Thomas Andrews...  200 rolls?  really?  Why would the 1 come up on the last of 200 rolls?  I assume shai is asking for 1 trial how many rolls are expected before we see get a 1.

Comment: Also, what do you mean roll a 1?  Do you mean guaranteed to roll a 1 or on average get a 1 (that is, 50% chance per session)?  By session I mean you roll the die some fixed number of times such as 20 times (for example).